$f(x)=1 + {\int}_0^1 (x e ^ y + y e ^ x) f(y) dy$
$$f(x)=1 + {\int}_0^1(x e ^ y + y e ^ x)f(y)\cdot dy$$ where $x,y$ are independent variables.
If complete solution set of $x$ for which function $h(x)=f(x)+3x$ is strictly increasing is $(-\infty,k)$ then the value of $\left[\frac{4e^k}3\right]$ is? (where [.] denotes greatest integer function)
Can anyone explain the solution
Background research: Question is from Book written by Vikas gupta.
Similar answer: https://byjus.com/question-answer/let-f-x-1-displaystyle-int-limits-1-0-left-xe-y-ye-x-right/
This question is subset of it.]

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

It is strongly implied by your question that the integral should be $dy$, not $dx$.  Please check for any other typos while you're checking this.

Leibnitz integral rule should work

Your $dx$ should be $dy$.

Raman your question seems fine but the way you have presented it is just not the way of MSE and soon the question might be closed. Anyways i will post a solution if the solution seems satisfactory you shall not comment thanks or something like that but in case just upvote the answer and mark it as accepted

$$f(x)=1+x\underbrace{\int_0^1e^yf(y)dy}_{constant\ value\ (say\ a)}+e^x\underbrace{\int_0^1yf(y)dy}_{constant\ value\ (say\ b)}$$
So Let, $f(x)=1+ax+be^x$ where $$c=\int_0^1(xe^y+ye^x)f(y)dy$$
$$\implies a=\int_0^1e^yf(y)dy=\int_0^1e^y(1+ay+be^y)dy\implies a=e-1+a(1)+b\left({e^2-1\over2}\right)\implies b={-2\over e+1}$$
Also,
$$b=\int_0^1yf(y)dy=\int_0^1y(1+ay+be^y)dy\implies b=\frac 12+\frac a3+b(1)\implies a=\frac{-3}2$$
Now we have $f(x)=1-\frac{3x}2-{2\over e+1}e^x$
$f(x)+3x=1+\frac{3x}2-{2\over e+1}e^x=g(x)$
We need to find interval in which $g(x)$ is increasing.
$$g'(x)=\frac 32-{2\over e+1}e^x\gt0\implies e^x\lt \frac 34(e+1)\implies \frac 43e^k=(e+1)\implies\left[\frac 43e^k\right]=3$$
